# Why defining a wrapping method over another method with an implicit argument doesn't work?

Tags: scala, types

writing this fails type check:

```
val list = List(1,3,5,2,4)

list sortBy (i => -i) //this is ok

def wrappedSort[A,B](a: List[A])(by: A => B): List[A] = {
     a sortBy by
} // this fails type check

wrappedSort(list)(i => -i) //So this won't work either
```

We know the compile error is: `No implicit Ordering defined for B.`

To make it work I had to have the Wrapper method have the same implicit argument as the wrapped method's which is:

```
import math.Ordering

def wrappedSort[A,B](a: List[A])(by: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): List[A] = {
     a sortBy by
}
```

But this is quite annoying. when working to abstract or extend over some library code, I come across some complicated context bounds that I must re-implement manually. is there a workaround for this in which I don't have to specify the implicit argument in my own abstracions?

Comment: You only need to add `Ordering` context bound to `B`, like this: `def wrappedSort[A, B: Ordering]`

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Is there a way to sort a list without an ordering specified? No ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `PreDef` (which is in scope everywhere unless you specifically disable it in the compiler) there is an instance of `Ordering[Int]` available. Hence, the compiler doesn't fail because it's in scope and it knows the exact implicit it has to search to find. When you provide an abstract `B` with that function signature, you effectively tell the compiler that `B` will not be supplied with an `Ordering` for all `B` (which is effectively every single type in the known universe) and the requirement that `B` have an `Ordering` as dictated by the `sortBy` function on `List` is failed immediately.

There really isn't a way to avoid this nor should you want to avoid it at all. It's by design and a safety feature of the compiler.

Comment: Thank you this actually makes sense now that I'm deeeeply thinking about it.